# How to filter SQL dataset based off value in one column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with this structure:

```
╔══════╦════╦═════════╗
║ Comp ║ ID ║  Desc   ║
╠══════╬════╬═════════╣
║    1 ║  1 ║ Comp1-1 ║
║    1 ║  2 ║ Comp1-2 ║
║    3 ║  2 ║ Comp3-2 ║
║    1 ║  3 ║ Comp1-3 ║
║    1 ║  4 ║ Comp1-4 ║
║    3 ║  5 ║ Comp3-5 ║
╚══════╩════╩═════════╝
```

The dataset I'm creating should have a unique ID.

If an ID exists in Comp1, use that Desc.

If it does not exist in Comp1, use Comp3.

End result should look like this instead:

```
╔══════╦════╦═════════╗
║ Comp ║ ID ║  Desc   ║
╠══════╬════╬═════════╣
║    1 ║  1 ║ Comp1-1 ║
║    1 ║  2 ║ Comp1-2 ║
║    1 ║  3 ║ Comp1-3 ║
║    1 ║  4 ║ Comp1-4 ║
║    3 ║  5 ║ Comp3-5 ║
╚══════╩════╩═════════╝
```

I've tried using `NOT EXISTS` and joining with a subquery but I'm not sure what to Join on.

Comment: Tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Using `not exists`, it looks like:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.descr like 'Comp1-%' or
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and t2.descr like 'Comp1-%'
                 );
```